# Solution to moment problem imply MaxEnt solution

Tags: moments, maximum-entropy

I have a moment problem with *arbitrary* moment functions $f_i$ and a finite number of constraints,
$$
\int p(x) f_i(x) dx = c_i.
$$
Does the existence of an exact Pade solution of the form,
$$
p(x) = \sum \kappa_i \delta(x - x_i),
$$
imply the existence of a solution to the maximum entropy (MaxEnt) problem of the form
$$
p(x) = \exp\left(\sum\lambda_i f_i(x)\right)
$$

Naively, I would have thought so, and I believe it is proven in the traditional problem $f_i(x) = x^i$. For the traditional problem, Hausdorff's condition for the full moment problem coincide with the condition for a MaxEnt solution. However, I don't know about this more generalized problem.

Comment: Usually we refer to Pade *approximations*. In this case are you saying the Pade solution is exact? Also are we assuming you are given a finite number of moments?

Comment: Yes, the Pade solution is exact, and yes, the number of moments is finite.